# in C++ instance fields are not initialized to their default. How about static fields?

Tags: c++, static, field

If I am not mistaken if I were to declare a global char array, its elements would be initialized to \0's. The same if I were to declare a static global or a static local. But what about a static field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  In C++ terminology, a field is called a "data member".

Paragraph 9.4.2.7 of the C++03 standard states "Static data members are initialized and destroyed exactly like non-local objects.".

Section 3.7.1 "Static storage duration" states "All objects which neither have dynamic storage duration nor are local have static storage duration."

Section 3.6.2 "Initialization of non-local objects" states "Objects with static storage duration shall be zero-initialized before any other initialization takes place."

So, if you don't explicitly initialize your data member to something else, it keeps its zero-initialized value.

Answer (score 1):

Static data members are treated the same as global variables with respect to initialization.